# Thymleaf: Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Consider I have the following form, which i send two parameters `_id` and `poID` to the controller:

```
 <form style='float:left; padding:5px; height:0px' th:object="${plant}"  th:method="post" th:action="@{/dashboard/DeliverPlant/{_id}(_id=${plant._id})/{po_id}(po_id=${plant.poID})}">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit">Verify Plant Delivery</button>
                   </form>
```

And in the controller i have the following form:

```
 @RequestMapping(method=POST, path="DeliverPlant/{_id}/{po_id}")
     public String DeliverPlant(Model model,@PathVariable("_id") String id,@PathVariable("po_id") String po_id) throws Exception {                  
            Long Id=    Long.parseLong(id);
         System.out.println("po_id is..................."+po_id+ "_id is:   "+id);


            return "dashboard/orders/ShowPOs";
      }
```

When i send my request, there is no internal error but it complains that

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

It seems that it cannot recognize the method.
So how can i fix it?

Update:

I also tried this

```
<form style='float:left; padding:5px; height:0px' th:object="${plant}"  th:method="post" th:action="@{'/dashboard/DeliverPlant/'+{_id}(_id=${plant._id})+'/'+{po_id}(po_id=${plant.poID})}">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="submit">Verify Plant Delivery</button>
                   </form>
```

Comment: @Tobías ..............

Comment: @hutchonoid ................

Comment: Increasing the logging level may shed some light on the problem. Try turning up the logging level for `org.springframework.web` to `DEBUG`. If you're using Spring Boot, just add this line to your application.properties file: `logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG`. Then post the relevant part of the logs.

Comment: Also post the generated html. I think you should build the url like: `th:action="@{/dashboard/DeliverPlant/{_id}/{po_id}(_id=${plant._id}, po_id=${plant.poID})}" method="POST"`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
method="POST"
```

instead of

```
th:method="POST"
```

Also, in your Controller class try

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST
```

where RequestMethod is *org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod*

Answer (score 0):

You return controller in modelAndView.addobject "po", "plant", "??".

You take object value in return page(select page).

"_id" <- ???
...
Anyway

edit path

```
th:action="@{/dashboard/deliver/plant/__${??.id}__/__${plant.id}__/__${po.id}__ }"
```

edit controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value ="/deliver/plant/{??.id}/{plant.id}/{po.id}")
public String DeliverPlant(@PathVariable("??.id") int id, @PathVariable("po.id") int poId, @PathVariable("plant.id") int plantId)  {                  

     return "dashboard/orders/ShowPOs"; // <-- break point. 
}
```

You try debug.

See value.